# Prettier works different on save using VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I've updated prettier to 2.8.0. When I run `npx prettier --version` I get 2.8.0 correctly.

My editor settings are like this:

[image]

When I run `npx prettier --write` I get the result below:

[image]

When I save the file it changes:

[image]

I want to run prettier when I save the file but it doesn't work as intended. What am I doing wrong here?